# Creating multiple classes from list of lists

Tags: python, class, oop, object

I have a list of lists as follows:

`list = [['SYDNEY', 'to', 'SAN FRANCISCO'], ['SYDNEY', 'from' 'AUCKLAND'], ['HONG KONG', 'to', 'BEIJING'], ['TOKYO' 'to', 'SEOUL'], ['SAN FRANCISCO', 'from', 'LONDON'], ['SYDNEY', 'to', 'SHANGHAI'], ['KL', 'to', 'SYDNEY']]`

I also have a class called 'City'

```
class City:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.cityName= name
        self.to_or_from = []
        self.to_or_from_city = []
```

How can I use the `list` to create objects for each city. For example, for Sydney, the object should look like this:

```
cityName = Sydney
to_or_from = ['to', 'from', 'to']
to_or_from_city = ['SAN FRANCISCO', 'AUCKLAND', 'SHANGHAI']
```

Please note that there is no need to consider `KL` in the `Sydney` object, however, the `KL` object should contain `Sydney` as follows:

```
cityName = KL
to_or_from = ['to']
to_or_from_city = ['SYDNEY']
```

In other words, if we have `['City1', 'to', 'City2']`, then the `City2` object does not need to contain a 'from' `City1`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your attempt

Comment: Do not name your lists as `list`.

Comment: Why not use a `dict`? Do you absolutely have to use classes? You can have the `city_name` as the key and a list of `[('to', 'Sydney'), ('from', 'Greece')]` as the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: How can I use the `_list` to create a `class City` object for each city

```
_list = [['SYDNEY', 'to', 'SAN FRANCISCO'], 
         ['SYDNEY', 'from', 'AUCKLAND'], 
         ['HONG KONG', 'to', 'BEIJING'], 
         ['TOKYO', 'to', 'SEOUL'], 
         ['SAN FRANCISCO', 'from', 'LONDON'], 
         ['SYDNEY', 'to', 'SHANGHAI'], 
         ['KL', 'to', 'SYDNEY']
        ]

class City:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.cityName= name
        self.to_or_from = []
        self.to_or_from_city = []

    def append(self, relation):
        c1, r, c2 = relation
        self.to_or_from.append(r)
        self.to_or_from_city.append(c2)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'City:{}, {}'.format(self.to_or_from, self.to_or_from_city)

cities = {}
for relation in _list:
    name = relation[0]
    cities.setdefault(name, City(name)).append(relation)

for name, city  in cities.items():
    print('{}:{}'.format(name, city))
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> SYDNEY:City:['to', 'from', 'to'], ['SAN FRANCISCO', 'AUCKLAND', 'SHANGHAI']
> HONG KONG:City:['to'], ['BEIJING']
> TOKYO:City:['to'], ['SEOUL']
> SAN FRANCISCO:City:['from'], ['LONDON']
> KL:City:['to'], ['SYDNEY']
> ```